# Criteria Query - Search for Integer using "like"

Tags: jpa, integer

How I can cast Integer to a String for Criteria Query?

i.e.:

```
Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.like((Expression) root.get(filterKey),
                    "%" + filterValue + "%");
```

I wan to create filter for dataTable component.... and i.e. for ID value I want to get filter like this:

*If I type "1" I will get all items with ID containing "1" (223122 ID will be still correct)*

Answer (score 24):

I have not used this myself, but this other question:

[Using JPA 2.0 Criteria API and cast causes generated JPQL to fail in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269389/using-jpa-2-0-criteria-api-and-cast-causes-generated-jpql-to-fail-in-hibernate)

Suggests using `.as(String.class)` after `root.get(filterKey)` to accomplish what you want.

If you're using Hibernate, be aware of [reported](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-5755) [bugs](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBPAPP-8075?_sscc=t)

Answer (score 17):

Try it

```
Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.like(root.get(filterKey).as(String.class),
                    "%" + filterValue + "%");
```

Comment: Just to confirm this solution works perfectly, nice thx! +1 from me

Answer (score 4):

This solved problem for me:

```
Expression<String> filterKeyExp = root.get(filterKey).as(String.class);
filterKeyExp = criteriaBuilder.lower(filterKeyExp);

Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.like(filterKeyExp ,"%" + filterValue.trim().toLowerCase() + "%");
```