# How to use like condition in JPA 2.0 - Hibernate for Criteria Builder

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have the following in DAO class for my filter condition

```
ParameterExpression<Long> pexp = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Long.class,"empNo");

criteria.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(emp.get(Employee_.empNo),pexp));
```

As you can see my empNo is of type Long, how can I use if I would want to use like instead of
equal? I tried as

```
criteria.add(criteriaBuilder.like(emp.<Long>get(Employee_.empNo), pexp)); // gives compilation errors
```

**Edit 1**

I have tried the following as well

```
criteria.add(criteriaBuilder.like(emp.<String>get(Employee_.empNo.toString()),
pexp.toString()));

and this as well

criteria.add(criteriaBuilder.like(emp.<String>get(String.valueOf(Employee_.empNo)),
String.valueOf(pexp)));
```

However when I run I am getting the following exception

```
Unable to resolve attribute [org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.SingularAttributeImpl$Identifier@a21c8
a] against path
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve attribute [org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.Singula
rAttributeImpl$Identifier@a21c8a] against path
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.unknownAttribute(AbstractPathImpl.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.locateAttribute(AbstractPathImpl.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.get(AbstractPathImpl.java:192)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269389/using-jpa-2-0-criteria-api-and-cast-causes-generated-jpql-to-fail-in-hibernate

Comment: @perissf How to resolve this issue? If it is a bug, which version has the bug being fixed? I am using Hibernate 4.0