# Aggregation on field returns org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute query in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have a field wth the type- SMALLINT(5) in my table in mysql database.

When i try to do a aggregate operation (sum()) on the field using projections,
I get the following exception

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLDataException: 
'8.0042892E7' in column '1' is outside valid range for the datatype SMALLINT.
```

I understood it as "aggregate operations results are returned in the same datatype in which it is stored". iS my assumption correct.

If so,Is it possible for me to cast the return value to a long value or a String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, your assumption is right, that the aggregate operation result returns the same datatype in which the attribute is stored. Of course that's why you see the error message "outside valid range": a SMALLINT is between -32768 and 32767 signed, or 0 and 65535 unsigned. `8.0042892E7` is far to large for this data type.

However it is possible to cast the result to an INT:

```
CAST(SUM(whatever) as INT)
```

For an INT the range is [-2147483648, 2147483647] for signed integer, and [0, 4294967295] for unsigned.

Comment: I have tried running your suggestion as Query and it works, is there an equivalent way of writing this using criteria.setprojection

Comment: i never tried it. HQL supports CAST if the underlying database supports it. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269389/using-jpa-2-0-criteria-api-and-cast-causes-generated-jpql-to-fail-in-hibernate using it with the Criteria API fails at least for older Hibernate versions.