# JPA 2.0 - casting column type from string to long using as from Expression class causing exception

Tags: jpa-2.0

I want to cast column from string to long to use the `cb.between()` functionality.

```
cb.between(number.as(Long.class), Long.valueOf(startNumber), Long.valueOf(endNumber));
```

number is `Path<String>`

Getting an exception as expecting CLOSE, found '(' near line 1, column 967...[query] 
At char 967 of the query, its '(' in `numeric(19,0)` within query, it is not forming query using bigint, instead numeric.

In junit its working properly where in query bigint is generated in it.

I have also gone through below, please let me know how to solve the problem.

[Using JPA 2.0 Criteria API and cast causes generated JPQL to fail in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269389/using-jpa-2-0-criteria-api-and-cast-causes-generated-jpql-to-fail-in-hibernate)

Best Regards,
Soheb Shaikh

Comment: Any one any answers, please

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a set of numbers having all numbers from Start to end number and then used in.

So no need to use between operator.

Best Regards,
Soheb Shaikh