# Using JPA 2.0 Criteria API to perform like on Long value

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have following data structure stored in my database:

```
public class Company{
    ...
    Long companyNumber;
    ...
}
```

Now I want to perform `Like` search on this particular column. As stated in some similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269389/using-jpa-2-0-criteria-api-and-cast-causes-generated-jpql-to-fail-in-hibernate), I'm trying to do a `.as(String.class)` on criteria builder inside my specification class:

```
public class CompanySpecification implements Specification<Company> { 

private String searchFilter;

@Override
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Company> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
    ...
    orPredicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(root.get(Company_.companyNumber).as(String.class), "%" + searchFilter + "%"));
    ...
}
```

However the following implementation works only on the first character. For example:

If is search for string value `9`, this predicate returns all Companies where `9` is part of companyNumber (`1119`, `1191`, `1911`, `9111`) but when I search for values with more then one character, no results are found. For example: if i search for `91`, no results are found even though there are companies in db with company numbers containing `91`: `1191`, `1911`, `9111`. I'm stuck on this, could you please point where have i made a mistake?

**EDIT**

added definition of `searchFilter`, search filter is set via constructor:

```
CompanySpecification companySpecification = new CompanySpecification(searchParameter);
```

where search parameter is passed as request parameter

Comment: Can you expand your code to include the declaration and value of `searchFilter`?

Comment: @SeanMickey code expanded and explained how search filter is passed to application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the above code works fine, the issue was that search was performed with pagination and number of requested page was higher than max results, therefore returned result list was empty.